# Formula for contrast ratio threshold in CIELAB space

Tags: css, web, colors, color-scheme

As mentioned in WCAG guidelines, the contrast ratio between background and foreground colors should be atleast 4.5:1 as shown in http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/Overview.html#IEC-4WD

But the formula mentioned above is for RGB format colors(Ctrl+f 'sRGB' to see the formula). I am dealing with CIELAB space, so can this formula be converted for CIELAB space? Or can we get a similar threshold in CIELAB distance form?

My observations 
There is no one to one mapping between CIELAB distance between two colors and the contrast ratio between same two colors in RGB format.

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

To directly answer your question, all you need to do is take the L* from CIELAB, And linearize it back to Y of CIEXYZ, then use Y for the WCAG2 L1 or L2 value.

**WCAG_2's L1 and L2 are just plain Y from CIEXYZ.**

```js
/////  from the SeeStars JS micro library 
/////  https://github.com/Myndex/seestars/


export function LstarToY(Lstar) {
    // Convert Lstar to D65 Y reference 1.0

    // from CIE standard, which now defines these as rational fractions
    const epsilon = 216/24389;  // 6^3/29^3
    const kappa = 24389/27;   // 29^3/3^3  
    const thresh = kappa * epsilon;  // (29^3/3^3) * (6^3/29^3)
  
    return Lstar > thresh ? Math.pow((Lstar + 16) / 116,3) : Lstar / kappa;
}
```

*Then you can use the flawed WCAG2 math to provide that spiffy less-than-useful result it's known for*

## Longer answer

I am on record pointing out that the WCAG 2 contrast guidelines  are significantly flawed. There are other methods and guidelines for better actual readability.

*Disclaimer: I am research lead for APCA™ the Accessible Perceptual Contrast Algorithm and related guidelines.*

WCAG 2 contrast is not perceptually uniform cross the visual range, and for instance it cannot be used for calculating dark mode.

APCA however can calculate both light mode and dark mode because it is perceptually uniform based on human perception of contrast of high spatial frequency stimuli on self-illuminated displays.

For a brief overview see why [APCA](https://git.apcacontrast.com/documentation/WhyAPCA)

### Delta Phi Star ✴︎

If you're already in CIELAB and you'd like to have a contrast value that's close to the perceptually uniform APCA, but simpler, then there is a super-simple quasi-perceptually-uniform method called ✴︎ [(delta phi star) or DPS Contrast](https://github.com/Myndex/deltaphistar).

Take the L star from your CIELAB colors, and:

```js
/////  from the Delta Phi Star repo
/////  https://github.com/Myndex/deltaphistar/

    deltaPhiStarLc = (Math.abs(bgLstar ** 1.618 - txLstar ** 1.618) ** 0.618) * 1.414 - 40 ;
    
    // A**B is the exponential operator equiv to Math.pow(A,B)
```

Though once again, the DPS values do not relate to WCAG2, but are reasonably close to [APCA](https://www.myndex.com/APCA/) for the important range of Lc45 to Lc75.